# Design a connected graph with smallest diameter

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G_k$ be any connected graph with $2^k$ vertices and the degree of each vertex being $k$. How to design a $G_k$ with smallest [diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory))?

The lower bound of the smallest diameter can be estimated by (inspired by Sfarla):
\begin{align*}
2^k &\leq 1+k+k(k-1)+\ldots+k(k-1)^{d-1}\\
&= 1+k\frac{(k-1)^d-1}{k-2}\\
\end{align*}So, 
\begin{align*}d &\geq \log_{k-1}\left\lceil \frac{(2^k-1)(k-2)}{k}+1 \right\rceil\\
&= O\left(\frac{k}{\log_2k}\right)
\end{align*}

The first three graphs are:

[image: G1,2,3 with smallest diameter]

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for $k>1$ the diameter $d$ of an undirected graph with $2^k$ vertices and $k2^{k-1}$ edges is always greater than $1$. This is because it can not be complete.

Moreover, let $n$ and $e$ be positive integers, whenever $e \geq n-1$, you can always design an undirected graph with $n$ vertices and $e$ edges whose diameter is at most $2$. For example, let $G=(V,E)$, with

$$V=\left\{x_1, \ldots, x_n \right\},$$

and impose that the set

$$ \left\{(x_1,x_i)\,|\, i=2,\ldots, n\right\} \subseteq E.$$

Then the distance between every pair of vertices is at most $2$.

This should answer your question, since the smallest diameter is $2$ for $k>1$.

Comment: Well, you are right. I need to modify my question.

Comment: Ok, now my answer is not correct anymore!

Comment: In this case the smallest diameter should be $\lceil \log_k(2^k-1) \rceil$

Comment: I also guess the smallest diameter is related to $k/\log_2 k$. Your conclusion is very precise. Can you prove it?

Comment: I believe I was wrong. But I'm sure that the diameter satisfies the inequality $d\geq \lceil \log_{k-1}(\frac{(2^k-1)(k-2)}{k}+1)\rceil+1$

Comment: @Sfarla This problem is similar to  diameter of expander graph. Expander graph are regular graphs that have high connectivity and relatively low diameter.  (they are sparse graph with relative low diameter and high connectivity). Maybe the bounds on diameter of expander graph will help!!

Comment: Ok. It's $d \geq \lceil \log_{k-1}(\frac{(2^k-1)(k-2)}{k}+1)\rceil$ for $k>2$